# Opinion on inheriting a previous model

Tags: python, django, inheritance, model

I am looking at my code and see that those two models have multiple similar fields. I was wondering if my ParentProfile model could inherit my User model in order to shorten the code and remove overlap. This is quite a beginner question and would like someone else's opinion on this matter. Thank you!

models.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    child_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    parent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True) # can login
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False) # staff user, not superuser
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False) # superuser

    objects = UserManager()

    # takes email as username | removes email
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, onj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app 'app_label'?"
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active

class ParentProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    child_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    parent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True) # can login
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False) # staff user, not superuser
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False) # superuser

    objects = UserManager()

    # takes email as username | removes email
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'child_first_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, onj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app 'app_label'?"
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active
```

Comment: Why do you have two identical models in the first place?

Comment: The second model has an extra field. Will inheriting the first model and simply adding in the extra field as child_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255) work as well as gaining all the functions of the first model. Or should I just add in the extra field in my form and scrap this whole model

Answer (score 1):

You can create Abstract Model with commons fields and inherit in Both

```
class CommonFieldModel(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    child_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    parent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True) # can login
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False) # staff user, not superuser
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False) # superuser

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

As defined by `Meta` class it is an abstract model and Django will not create any table for this. Now you can inherit this model in your other model. Ex.

```
class ParentProfile(CommonFieldModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
class User(CommonFieldModel, AbstractBaseUser):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```